# Kvazaar encoder - Reading ROI file failed

Tags: encoder, roi, hevc

While trying this command:

```
kvazaar -i video.yuv --input-res 1280x720 -o video_tiled.hevc --roi roi.txt --slices tiles
```

I get this error:

```
Reading ROI file failed.
invalid argument: roi=roi.txt
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you give the version of the encoder? `kvazaar --version`

Comment: Can you specify the content of `roi.txt`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Ahresse. The version of Kvazaar is v1.1.0
and the content of roi.txt is: 64 64 20 40 40

64 64 20 40 40

64 64 20 40 40

Comment: Then `roi.txt` should contain "64 64 " followed by <64*64  = 4096> values.

Comment: Understood, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `roi.txt` file must be incomplete and inadequate to the specified size.

About the `roi.txt` file:

> (...) the first two values are the width and height, followed by
>   width*height delta QP values in raster order.

Here is a link to the source code giving the error: [ https://github.com/ultravideo/kvazaar/blob/f8c5bb18a4604175f20dea673d14ca66257ac0c0/src/cfg.c#L1103 ]